# PHP file copy function

Tags: php, html, web

i've been creating a user file system for my site. I'm trying to make it so right as soon as someone registers on the register.php page it copies the index.php file in my error folder to the users profile picture folder. 
Here is a tree of my web folder:
`error/index.php, nofile.png
index.php
register.php
members/0,1,2,3,4,etc to 30. - User id's, new one made whenever someone signs up.`
. 
I want the file from the error folder to copy into the members/$id folder when someone registers to my website.
Please help, 
-Matt.

Comment: What is the overall goal of this design?  Why do you want a folder per-user?

Comment: you could simply use Apache's `mod_rewrite`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in register.php use function copy:

```
 copy("error/index.php", "member/x/index.php");
```

Where x is the number assigned to the new user

The function copy the first argument file to the second one.

Comment: hey, just tried that snippet of code but it still doesn't create the index.php file in the users id folder inside the members folder.

Comment: Please provide the piece of your code that manage the copy of the file!

Comment: The php code of your register.php where you added the instruction: copy("error/index.php", "member/x/index.php");

Comment: In your code after the new member has been inserted into the db you create the proper member's folder structure ... mkdir("members/$id", 0755);..... after you are done with it insert: copy("error/index.php", "member/{$id}/index.php"); check the correctness of the path! to correctrly run my paths the page executing the php instruction shloud be in the directory containing error and members folders

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php 
 copy ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/error/index.php" , $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/members/".$id."/index.php"); // $id is the user id like folder id
 ?>
```

it will copy index.php

thanks